# regular expression code

Tags: regex, perl, debugging

I need to find match between two tab delimited files files like this:

File 1:

```
ID1  1  65383896    65383896    G   C  PCNXL3
ID1  2  56788990        55678900        T       A  ACT1 
ID1  1   56788990       55678900       T       A  PRO55
```

File 2

```
ID2 34    65383896   65383896       G   C  MET5
ID2  2   56788990       55678900       T       A  ACT1 
ID2  2   56788990       55678900       T       A  HLA
```

what I would like to do is to retrive the matching line between the two file. What I would like to match is everyting after the gene ID

So far I have written this code but unfortunately perl keeps giving me the error:
use of  "Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//)"

Could you please help me figure out where i am doing it wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
use strict;

open (INA, $ARGV[0]) || die "cannot to open gene file";
open (INB, $ARGV[1]) || die "cannot to open coding_annotated.var files";

my @sample1 = <INA>;
my @sample2 = <INB>;

foreach my $line (@sample1) {
    my @tab = split (/\t/, $line);

    my $chr   = $tab[1];
    my $start = $tab[2];
    my $end   = $tab[3];
    my $ref   = $tab[4];
    my $alt   = $tab[5];
    my $name  = $tab[6];

    foreach my $item (@sample2){
        my @fields = split (/\t/,$item);

        if (   $fields[1] =~ m/$chr(.*)/
            && $fields[2] =~ m/$start(.*)/
            && $fields[4] =~ m/$ref(.*)/
            && $fields[5] =~ m/$alt(.*)/
            && $fields[6] =~ m/$name(.*)/
        ) {     
            print  $line, "\n", $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for the output format of the code, But i do not way it did not recognize the whole code in ``  but I had to do it line by line.

Comment: The backticks are only for short parts of code within a row. For a long part of code, just mark it and press ctrl + k, or use the button at the top of the editor, or indent each row by 4 spaces.

Comment: I am getting some output for the same program. Perl does not show any error. Could you plz check again. I mean I had the same line in two input files, and it displayed the lines.

Comment: For your problem, it is (at the moment) not regex related, you need to debug your code. Check the values of your arrays `@tab` and `@fields`, there are uninitialized values. Maybe you have empty or incomplete rows in your source files.

Comment: Right! I have some empty lines in the original files. I forgot to remove then. Thanks for the advice. I will try now.

Comment: more or less 1,500 bytes each. Why?

Answer (score 1):

On its surface your code seems to be fine (although I didn't debug it). If you don't have an error I cannot spot, could be that the input data has RE special character, which will confuse the regular expression engine when you put it as is (e.g. if any of the variable has the '$' character). Could also be that instead of tab you have spaces some where, in which case you'll indeed get an error, because your split will fail.

In any case, you'll be better off composing just one regular expression that contains all the fields. My code below is a little bit more Perl Idiomatic. I like using the implicit $_ which in my opinion makes the code more readable. I just tested it with your input files and it does the job.

```
use strict;

open (INA, $ARGV[0]) or die "cannot open file 1";
open (INB, $ARGV[1]) or die "cannot open file 2";

my @sample1 = <INA>;
my @sample2 = <INB>;


foreach (@sample1) {
    (my $id, my $chr, my $start, my $end, my $ref, my $alt, my $name) =
        m/^(ID\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;
    my $rex = "^ID\\d+\\s+$chr\\s+$start\\s+$end\\s+$ref\\s+$alt\\s+$name\\s+";
    #print "$rex\n";
    foreach (@sample2) {
        if( m/$rex/ ) {
            print "$id - $_";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, how regular is the input data? Do you have exactly one tab between the fields? If that is the case, there is no point to split the lines into 7 different fields - you only need two: the ID portion of the line, and the rest. The first regex would be

```
(my $id, my $restOfLine) = m/^(ID\d+)\s+(.*)$/;
```

And you are searching $restOfLine within the second file in a similar technique as above.

If your files are **huge** and performance is an issue, you should consider putting the first regular expressions (or strings) in a map. That will give you O(n*log(m)) where n and m are the number of lines in each file.

Finally, I have a similar challenge when I need to compare logs. The logs are supposed to be identical, with the exception of a time mark at the beginning of each line. But more importantly: most lines are the same *and in order*. If this is what you have, and it make sense for you, you can:

1. First remove the IDxxx from each line: `perl -pe "s/ID\d+ +//"` file >cleanfile
2. Then use BeyondCompare or Windiff to compare the files.

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit with your code. What you wrote there was actually three loops:

- one over the lines of the first file,
- one over the lines of the second file, and
- one over all fields in these lines. You manually unrolled this loop.

> The rest of this answer assumes that the files are strictly tab-seperated and that any other whitespace *matters* (even at the end of fields and lines).

Here is a condensed version of the code (assumes open filehandles `$file1`, `$file2`, and `use strict`):

```
my @sample2 = <$file2>;

SAMPLE_1:
foreach my $s1 (<$file1>) {
    my (undef, @fields1) = split /\t/, $s1;
    my @regexens = map qr{\Q$_\E(.*)}, @fields1;

    SAMPLE_2:
    foreach my $s2 (@sample2) {
        my (undef, @fields2) = split /\t/, $s2;
        for my $i (0 .. $#regexens) {
            $fields2[$i] =~ $regexens[$i] or next SAMPLE_2;
        }
        # only gets here if all regexes matched
        print $s1, $s2;
    }
}
```

I did some optimisations: precompiling the various regexes and storing them in an array, quoting the contents of the fields etc. However, this algorithm is *O(n²)*, which is bad.

Here is an elegant variant of that algorithm that *knows* that only the first field is different — the rest of the line has to be the same *character for character*:

```
my @sample2 = <$file2>;

foreach my $s1 (<$file1>) {
    foreach my $s2 (@sample2) {
        print $s1, $s2 if (split /\t/, $s1, 2)[1] eq (split /\t/, $s2, 2)[1];
    }
}
```

I just test for string equality of the rest of the line. While this algorithm is still *O(n²)*, it outperforms the first solution roughly by an order of magnitude simply by avoiding braindead regexes here.

Finally, here is an *O(n)* solution. It is a variant of the previous one, but executes the loops *after* each other, not *inside* each other, therefore finishing in linear time. We use hashes:

```
# first loop via map    
my %seen = map {reverse(split /\t/, $_, 2)}
           # map {/\S/ ? $_ : () } # uncomment this line to handle empty lines
           <$file1>;

# 2nd loop
foreach my $line (<$file2>) {
    my ($id2, $key) = split /\t/, $line, 2;
    if (defined (my $id1 = $seen{$key})) {
        print "$id1\t$key";
        print "$id2\t$key";
    }
}
```

`%seen` is a hash that has the rest of the line as a key and the first field as a value. In the second loop, we retrieve the rest of the line again. If this line was present in the first file, we reconstruct the whole line and print it out. This solution is better than the others and scales well up- and downwards, because of its linear complexity

Comment: The final algorithm is O(n*log(n)). Lookup in the map has a price.

Comment: @Uri Actually, no. (Well, of course there is a price, but a rather small one). Lookup in a C++ map/ordered list is *O(log n)*, but lookup in a hashtable is almost *O(1)*. In Perl, the `%` sigil declares the hash type, while `map` denotes the higher-order function, not a data type.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Slurp;
use strict;

my ($ina, $inb) = @ARGV;

my @lines_a = File::Slurp::read_file($ina);
my @lines_b = File::Slurp::read_file($inb);

my $table_b = {};

my $ln = 0;

# Store all lines in second file in a hash with every different value as a hash key
# If there are several identical ones we store them also, so the hash values are lists  containing the id and line number
foreach (@lines_b) {
    chomp; # strip newlines
    $ln++; # count current line number 
    my ($id, $rest) = split(m{[\t\s]+}, $_, 2); # split on whitespaces, could be too many tabs or spaces instead
    if (exists $table_b->{$rest}) {
        push @{ $table_b->{$rest} }, [$id, $ln]; # push to existing list if we already found an entry that is the same
    } else {
        $table_b->{$rest} = [ [$id, $ln] ]; # create new entry if this is the first one
    }
} 

# Go thru first file and print out all matches we might have
$ln = 0;
foreach (@lines_a) {
    chomp;
    $ln++; 
    my ($id, $rest) = split(m{[\t\s]+}, $_, 2);
    if (exists $table_b->{$rest}) { # if we have this entry print where it is found
        print "$ina:$ln:\t\t'$id\t$rest'\n " . (join '\n ', map { "$inb:$_->[1]:\t\t'$_->[0]\t$rest'" } @{ $table_b->{$rest} }) . "\n";
    }
}
```